# How to make url that starts with the app name and then the website name? (i.e maps.google.com)

Tags: url, web

I have seen quite a few sites that break that have urls that consist of [app-name].[site-name].com. Like docs.google.com and maps.google.com. How can I do this? Does it involve buying more than the base domain name? What type of url routing is necessary?

Comment: Just add subdomains to your domain and configure your webserver accordingly.

Comment: The domain name is just "google.com".  Anything you prepend to that is configured in your DNS.  You can have "maps.google.com", "docs.google.com", "this.is.a.subdomain.google.com", etc.  All you need to do is configure your DNS entries.